# Did the Prophet (s) allow a female-like man

Tags: men-women

Once I heard a hadith (I am not sure of the exact text) where the Prophet (s) allows a female-like man to be with women. But after he described them to the other men in a way as if you could see them, he forbade it.
What is a female-like man and is it allowed to be that way?

Comment: It would be better if you could find the hadith, search it on sunnah.com or other websites.

Answer (score 1):

The hadith you seem to be referring to is the one where there was a مخنث (effeminate man) who utterred something obscene in the presence of the wives of the prophet ﷺ.

> عن أم سلمة، أن النبي صلى الله عليه وسلم كان عندها وفي البيت مخنث، فقال المخنث لأخي أم سلمة عبد الله بن أبي أمية إن فتح الله عليكم الطائف غدا أدلك على ابنة غيلان، فإنها تقبل بأربع وتدبر بثمان‏.‏ فقال النبي صلى الله عليه وسلم ‏ "‏ لا يدخلن هذا عليكن
>
> Narrated Um Salama:
>
> The Prophet (ﷺ) came to me while there was an effeminate man sitting with me, and I heard him (i.e. the effeminate man) saying to `Abdullah bin Abi Umaiya, "O Abdullah! See if Allah should make you conquer Ta'if tomorrow, then take the daughter of Ghailan (in marriage) as (she is so beautiful and fat that) she shows four folds of flesh when facing you, and eight when she turns her back." The Prophet (ﷺ) then said, "These (effeminate men) should never enter upon you."
>
> <sup>— [Bukhari](https://sunnah.com/bukhari:5235) and  [Muslim](https://sunnah.com/muslim:2181)</sup>

A مخنث is a person who is anatomically a male, but his behavior is like females, either from birth or as a choice. The former case is free from blame, whereas the latter case is condemned:

> لعن النبي صلى الله عليه وسلم المخنثين من الرجال، والمترجلات من النساء وقال ‏ ‏ أخرجوهم من بيوتكم
>
> The Prophet (ﷺ) cursed effeminate men (those men who are in the similitude (assume the manners of women) and those women who assume the manners of men, and he said, "Turn them out of your houses ."
>
> <sup>— [Bukhari](https://sunnah.com/bukhari:5886)</sup>